# How to prove the spectral radius satisfies the strict inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Let $A = a_{i,j}$ be a positive matrix, which not all of whose rows have the same sum. Prove the the spectral radius satisfies the strict inequalities

$$\displaystyle{\min_i}\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}<(A)<{\max_i}\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}$$

How would I go about proving this? I'm not sure what the inequalities are really stating.

I know that since A is positive, then the spectral radius is an element of the spectrum of $A$, so $\rho(A) \in \mbox{spectrum}(A)$. $A$ also has an eigenvector v(i)>0 and that Av = (A). But thats really it, how do I prove these inequalities. I don't understand it and how to go about it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can look at any book that deals with Perron-Frobenius Theory.

Comment: Here is a more general result. Let $A$ be any positive matrix and $x$ be any positive vector. Let $y$ be the entrywise division of $Ax$ by $x$. If $x$ is not the eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$, then $\rho(A)$ must lie strictly between the minimum and maximum values of the elements of $y$. In your case, $x$ is just the vector of ones.

Comment: Assume WLOG $\lambda_1=\rho(A) =1$.  If $A$ is not stochastic then use left Perron vector $\mathbf x^T A =\mathbf x^T$ where $\big\Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_1=1$.  Now compute $\mathbf x^T A \mathbf 1$ two different ways; what is the problem if $1=\lambda_1 \leq \min_i\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}$?  Also what is the problem if $1=\lambda_1 \geq \max_i\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}$